# Item (4) in Lurie's definition of the class of marked anodyne morphisms

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

I have a question concerning Remark 3.1.1.3 in Lurie's "Higher Topos Theory" about the definition of the class of marked anodyne morphisms. There, it is mentioned that "it suffices to allow $K$ to range over a set of representatives for all isomorphism classes of Kan complexes with only countably many simplices". Perhaps I'm wrong, but wouldn't it even be possible to replace the class (4) by the class (4') containing only the inclusion $K^{\flat} \hookrightarrow K^{\sharp}$, where $K$ is the simplicial set having two 0-simplices ( - $x$ and $y$ - ), two 1-simplices ( - one going from $x$ to $y$ and the other going from $y$ to $x$ - ), and two 2-simplices witnessing that the two 1-simplices shall be equivalences, and besides that only degenerate simplices.

This is intimately related to the proof of Proposition 3.1.1.6, specifically line 7 on page 150. There, $K$ is defined to denote the largest Kan complex contained in $X_{p(x)}$; but wouldn't it also be possible to define $K$ to be the simplicial set described above, and, after choosing an extension of $d_2(\sigma) : \Delta^1 \to X$ to $K$, argue that $d_2(\sigma)$ must be marked because $p$ has the right lifting property with respect to the inclusion $K^{\flat} \hookrightarrow K^{\sharp}$?

Comment: When you refer to the groupoid freely generated by $\Delta^1$, do you actually mean the groupoid in the sense of ordinary category theory (where the map of $\Delta^1$ has an actual inverse)? Or do you have something less structured in mind?

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I confused the groupoid freely generated by $\Delta^1$ with the "walking equivalence", i.e. the simplicial set having two 0-simplices ( - $x$ and $y$ - ), two 1-simplices ( - one going from $x$ to $y$ and the other going from $y$ to $x$ - ), and two 2-simplices witnessing the fact that the two 1-simplices shall be equivalences, and besides that only degenerate simplices. I will correct my post. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I'm hesitating because I'm not sure yet whether the inclusion $W^{\flat} \hookrightarrow W^{\sharp}$, where $W$ denotes the "walking equivalence", is marked anodyne at all. Let me sleep on that ...

Comment: I've convinced myself that, indeed, $W^{\flat} \hookrightarrow W^{\sharp}$ *is* marked anodyne.

Comment: @RooibosTee It's not clear to me that the simplicial set you describe is genuinely the "walking equivalence". I think there are some coherence issues. On the other hand, the nerve of the ordinary groupoid generated by $\Delta^1$ is a model for "fully coherent" equivalences.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Okay, I see; does the simplicial set $W$ which I *erroneously* called the "walking equivalence" have an official name?

Comment: Following the terminology of Baez (http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week173.html), the groupoid generated by $\Delta^1$ is the "walking adjoint equivalence", isn't it?

Comment: @RooibosTee: provided by “groupoid” you mean “∞-groupoid”, yes, the groupoid generated by Δ[1] is the walking equivalence.  But a pretty standard model for it is E^1, the 0-coskeletal simplicial set on two 0-cells.  Explicitly, its *n*-cells are just sequences of length *n* from {0,1}.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine you mean "walking *adjoint* equivalence"?

Comment: @RooibosTee: yes, always :-)  I notice now, though, that Zhen Lin had already mentioned E^1 by a different name, since it is exactly the nerve of the ordinary groupoid generated by Δ[1], which he suggests.